# i get error when i install laravel/ui for laravel version 7.3.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

> PS C:\wamp\www\pizzahouse> composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
> The 'http://repo.packagist.org/p/fideloper/proxy%243c476aa5bc1f7be4de12519b02c7d32e5271ecf43f8ad9119472305e52cc7d85.json
> ' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad URI
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []..

and my composer.json is

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue not too long ago with a Laravel 7 project and ran `composer require laravel/ui:^2.4` which worked. I hope this helps for you too.

Things have changed a bit with the release of Laravel 8 and the Jetstream package. See the Github page: https://github.com/laravel/ui